# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:26506

This type of error I am getting and the URL is not picked be the webdriver.
I am using chrome version 65.0
Chromedriver version 2.9

Could someone help me on this issue.

Comment: Hey, there is not enough Information. Please post entire test code and  stacktrace that we can help you.

Comment: Can you give us more information, probably some code that causes the error to happen?

Comment: public static String ChromeFolderPath = "chromedriver_win32/";
 public static String Chrome_FileName = "chromedriver.exe";
 public static String Chrome_Path = oDir + "/" + ChromeFolderPath + Chrome_FileName;
 static WebDriver driver;

 public WebDriver Browser(String URL) {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Chrome_Path);
  ChromeOptions cop = new ChromeOptions();
  cop.addArguments("disable-extensions");
  driver = new ChromeDriver(cop);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get(URL);

  return driver;

 }

Comment: Update the question with the _code trial_ and the _error stack trace_.